# How to have sudo -u user for all capistrano tasks that are to be run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, continuous-deployment, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

NOTE: I am using Capistrano 3.2.1 and Rails 4.1.1.

Basically I need Capistrano to append `sudo -u deploy-user` for all the tasks by default because of the server permissions arrangement on **my-remote-server**.

This is my config/deploy.rb file:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1

set :stages, %w(qaenv production)
set :default_stage, 'production'

set :application, "my_rails_app"
set :repo_url, 'git@my-git-server.com:repositories/my_rails_app.git'
set :domain, "my-remote-server"
set :database, "mysql"
set :use_sudo, true

#set :user, "surya"
set :deploy_user, "deploy-user"
set :migration_user, "www"
set :sample_user, "sample"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, port: 2445 }
#set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :branch, "master"
set :scm, :git

role :web, fetch(:domain)                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, fetch(:domain)                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  fetch(:domain), :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
set :pty, true
set :log_level, :trace
set :sudo, ' -u deploy-user ' # I hoped that it'll work, but it doesn't
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
```

Here's the error trace I get:

```
[surya@my-server my_rails_app]$ cap qaenv deploy:check:directories
INFO[0fe8c58d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_rails_app/shared /var/www/my_rails_app/releases on my-remote-server
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
Password: MySecretPassword
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host my-remote-server: Authentication failed for user deploy-user@my-remote-server
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2-p95/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:check:directories
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[surya@my-server my_rails_app]$
```

If you look at the error trace line:

```
INFO[0fe8c58d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_rails_app/shared /var/www/my_rails_app/releases on my-remote-server
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
Password: MySecretPassword
cap aborted!
Exception while executing on host my-remote-server: Authentication failed for user deploy-user@my-remote-server
```

It tries to run:

```
/usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_rails_app/shared /var/www/my_rails_app/releases
```

and what I want it do is:

```
sudo -u deploy-user /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/my_rails_app/shared /var/www/my_rails_app/releases
```

What do I do to make sure that my all cap tasks are run with `sudo -u deploy-user`?

Comment: Is the user you are using to deploy the same user that will be used to run the application?

Comment: No, user I am using to run the script is different than the user presented in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your deploy user has passwordless sudo access, and in your deploy.rb file make sure that use_sudo is set to true.

First, add this to your deploy.rb file.

```
set :use_sudo, true
```

Then edit your sudoers file and give your deploy user passwordless sudo. Just open the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add this line to the bottom of the file (assuming your user is named "deploy")

```
deploy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Note: This should not be done lightly. This is a security risk, and you should understand the implications before you do it. Granted, if you NEED sudo access for your deploy user then this is how you do it. For more details on why passwordless sudo is bad check out the documentation:

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. One thing I didn't understand you say: "in your deploy.rb file make sure that use_sudo is set to true." and then you put: `set :use_sudo, false`. What's really going on?

Comment: But I already have it set to true? Did you check the code in deploy.rb I posted?? I don't have sudo to ALL for deploy user :(.

Comment: It is likely that when you set your authorization for the deploy user that something did not work. Your error happens when cap is trying to create a folder, but it does not have the permissions. Though you shouldn't need sudo access for this; rather you need to authorize the deploy user to create the needed folders. Just [go to this page:](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/), and read the section titled "Authorisation." Especially look at the paragraph that starts with "To configure this hierarchy..."

Comment: Thank you buddy! But I have different problem altogether now.